# Java: Program chrashes after building with ant script

Tags: java, ant, build

I like to build my javafx application to a jar. I use the following ant script, which is mainly generated out of the fxbuild. I can build the jar, but the program crashes immediately. It can't find one of my library (see below). Does somebody know, why the jar isn't included?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="App" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="/path/to/repository/App/lib">
            <filename name="controlsfx-8.20.8.jar"/>    
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="/path/to/repository/App/lib">
            <filename name="org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.1.201410131835-r.jar"/>    
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="/path/to/repository/App/lib">
            <filename name="openjfx-dialogs-1.0.2.jar"/>    
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="/path/to/repository/App/lib">
            <filename name="jsch-0.1.51.jar"/>  
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="/path/to/repository/App">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.1.201410131835-r.jar"/>
            <include name="controlsfx-8.20.8.jar"/>
            <include name="openjfx-dialogs-1.0.2.jar"/>
            <include name="jsch-0.1.51.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- Copy project references -->
    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />
    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="App.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources> 
    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="App"
        mainClass="com.company.app.Main"
        toolkit="fx"
    />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />
    <fx:jar destfile="dist/App.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Company"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="App"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="2.0"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>
    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="App" nativeBundles="all"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:info title="App" vendor="Company"/>
        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 25 more
```

Comment: And you are sure that you are using the correct classpath when you start your application?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, what you mean. But I can start the programm with eclipse without problems

Comment: What I mean is: you are using ANT to build and bundle your application into a JAR file. But in order to RUN your application, this JAR file; and any other JAR file that is used to build your application needs to be in the Java class path. The reason you can run the app in eclipse is because eclipse is taking care of the class path (that is what your project setup is for). Long story short: you should really sit down and learn about concepts like "classpath" **now**.